# Retrieve/Display user Lync Presence status in iOS?

Tags: ios, .net, swift, lync

I know MS has a Lync SDK to retrieve user Lync Status using .Net frameworks , but does anyone tried or experienced to do the same in iOS for an iPhone/iPad App ?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use [UCWA](http://ucwa.lync.com/), the REST based Lync API. Note that this does require a working login on the Lync server.

Comment: Thanks , just what i was looking for , the exact detailed link is at https://ucwa.lync.com/login/explore

Answer (score 0):

The Lync SDK you are talking about is base on .Net. That means, you can invoke method like `login()` directly from that SDK using c# code. So that makes life much easier.

However, there is no such SDK written in swift. That means, you cannot directly contact lync though some simple code like `user.login()`. Lync only provides you a RESTful server. So for every single action you want to do, you have to create from scratch (HTTP calls) by yourself. You have to handle all the request parameters and respond key value pairs, etc.